# Rails post multi-step form data after signup with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two step form that saves data in a session and creates a new record assuming the user is logged in.

If a new user hasn't signed up I want him to be able to:

1. fill in form #1
2. fill in form #2
3. redirect to Devise signup (`new_registration_path`)
4. post/create record from the form data after signup/login is completed

see code below (**location_controller.rb**):

On: "`elsif @location.last_step`?", it directs to signup if user isn't logged in but doesn't save the data after login.

Is there a way to pass the session form data thought Devise so it posts/creates the record after signup?

Thanks in advance

> ```
> def new
>   session[:location_params] ||= {}
>     if current_user.nil?
>       @location = Location.new(session[:location_params])
>     else
>       @location = current_user.locations.new(session[:location_params])
>     end
>
>   @location.current_step = session[:location_step]
>
>   respond_to do |format|
>     format.html # new.html.erb
>     format.json { render json: @location }
>   end   
> end
>
> def create
>     session[:location_params].deep_merge!(params[:location]) if params[:location]
>     if current_user.nil?
>       @location = Location.new(session[:location_params])
>     else
>       @location = current_user.locations.new(session[:location_params])
>     end
>     @location.current_step = session[:location_step]
>     if @location.valid?   
>       if params[:back_button]
>         @location.previous_step
>       elsif @location.last_step?
>        @location.save
>       else
>         @location.next_step
>       end
>       session[:location_step] = @location.current_step
>     end
>
>     if @location.new_record?
>       render "new"
>     else
>       session[:location_step] = session[:location_params] = nil
>       flash[:notice] = "Trip saved!"
>       redirect_to @location
>     end
>   end
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

1. added `store_form_data(@location)` in locations.rb
2. store_form_data function in SessionHelper (see below)
3. added `include SessionsHelper` to application_controller.rb
4. added `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` function in application_controller.rb (see blow)

app/helpers/session_helper.rb:

> ```
> module SessionsHelper
>   def store_form_data(locations)
>     session[:form_data] = locations
>   end
> end
> ```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

> ```
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   protect_from_forgery
>   include SessionsHelper
>
>   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
>     if session[:form_data].present?
>       @user = current_user
>       @location = session[:form_data]
>       @user.locations << @location
>       session[:form_data] = nil
>       flash[:notice] = 'Trip saved!'
>       index_path
>     else
>       new_location_path
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

apps/controllers/locations_controller.rb:

> ```
>  def new
>     #@location = Location.new
>     session[:location_params] ||= {}
>     session[:form_data] = nil
>     if current_user.nil?
>       @location = Location.new(session[:location_params])
>     else
>       @location = current_user.locations.new(session[:location_params])
>     end
>
>     @location.current_step = session[:location_step]
>
>     respond_to do |format|
>       format.html # new.html.erb
>       format.json { render json: @location }
>     end
>   end
>
> def create
>     session[:location_params].deep_merge!(params[:location]) if params[:location]
>     if current_user.nil?
>       @location = Location.new(session[:location_params])
>     else
>       @location = current_user.locations.new(session[:location_params])
>     end
>     @location.current_step = session[:location_step]
>     if @location.valid?   
>       if params[:back_button]
>         @location.previous_step
>       elsif @location.last_step?
>         if current_user.nil?
>           store_form_data(@location)
>         end
>        @location.save
>       else
>         @location.next_step
>       end
>       session[:location_step] = @location.current_step
>     end
>
>     if @location.new_record?
>       render "new"
>     else
>       session[:location_step] = session[:location_params] = nil
>       flash[:notice] = "Trip saved!"
>       redirect_to @location
>     end
>   end
> ```

Comment: some related links:
http://blog.justinthiele.com/retaining-form-data-through-a-login-process-a/
http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1679-lazy-user-registration-for-rails-apps/